# Oauth 2 - token response with token_type "bearer" when it should be "Bearer"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have an api configured with ouath 2. The return configuration of the oauth / token endpoint by default came with the toke_type "bearer" (lower case) but I need it to be returned as "Bearer", what can I do to achieve this?

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

end

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `TokenEnhancer` interface.
Please refer to answer 1 from @Samir in this question: [Configure custom OAuth2AccessToken on a client Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205954/configure-custom-oauth2accesstoken-on-a-client-spring-boot-application)

and overwrite the `enhance` method as follows:

```
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setTokenType("Bearer");
    return accessToken;
}
```

}